# How to initialize formArray of formControl to a formGroup with the array received from @Output emitter in angular reactive forms?

Tags: angular

I know how to initialize formarray of formcontrol if we have the array value onInit itself. But here the case is different. I will get the array value from output of my child component only.

```
parentcomponent.html
--------------------
<app-peoplelist #appPeopleListing (usersByObject)="getUsersByCompany($event)" [requestObj]="requestObj"></app-peoplelist>

parentcomponent.ts
------------------
getUsersByCompany(value) {
  this.usersByCompanyArr = value.company;
}
```

So, I was stuck on this process of initializing formarray with the output array value. Any help would be highly encouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formcontrol.setvalue(value)`

Comment: can you explain me a bit more briefly or give me any reference links to check

Comment: I don't understand the code you've written. But what I understand from your question is that you have some kind of FormGroup / FormArray / FormControl where you want to set the value after you get it from your child component. To set any value on formcontrol, you can use setvalue method. See this for more information: [link](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value)

Comment: I need to create a formarray with the value I received from the child component, in order to display multi checkbox and to retrieve values.

Comment: @Mani_MR, can you re-write your question adding an example of data you received? are an array of booleans true/false, an array of string? You has problem to display the checkbox? Really I can not imagine you want to do